# In botframework-sdk all of a sudden my bot started to get this error Error: Get Token request returned http error: 401

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, direct-line-botframework

All of a sudden my bot started to get this error:

[onTurnError] unhandled error: Error: Get Token request returned http error: 401 and server response: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS7000222: The provided client secret keys are expired. Visit the Azure Portal to create new keys for your app, or consider using certificate credentials for added security: [https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials\r\nTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials%5Cr%5CnTrace) ID: 91097c7f-35a4-4f95-97bc-d616a6b45100\r\nCorrelation ID: e0110013-d13c-4897-aafc-f2e36a194ed5\r\nTimestamp: 2021-03-01 20:00:25Z","error_codes":[7000222],"timestamp":"2021-03-01 20:00:25Z","trace_id":"91097c7f-35a4-4f95-97bc-d616a6b45100","correlation_id":"e0110013-d13c-4897-aafc-f2e36a194ed5","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=7000222"}

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Direct Line secret has expired, assuming you are trying to hit `https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate`. You can regenerate them by going to the Bot Service blade, selecting your Bot Service, and then clicking on Channels. Click `Edit` on your Direct Line channel and you'll have the option to regenerate your key(s).

Comment: @Abhi did this solve your issue? If so please consider accepting and upvoting this answer.